# VBA chart creation from scattered data rows

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range

I'm creating a UI for entering, editing, exporting, importing patient data (cholesterol biomarkers).
I've encountered a problem with the need to display available data from a "Data" worksheet.

The Data looks like this:
[image]

What I need is to create a chart from available data of `,, Elizbeth Norton,,` with date in X-axis and `Chol, Trig, LDL, HDL` (separate lines) in Y-axis.

The results are being managed by using a Userform with a Listbox (from which a button should create the chart when found data is selected. Data is selected in a Listbox)
and this code finds needed data and puts selected results into an array

The Userform:

[image]

Code to find needed data:

```
If Len(f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value) >= 3 Then 'Do search if text in find box is longer than 3 character.
    
    Set SearchRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("C:E").Cells
    
    FindWhat = f_FindAll.TextBox_Find.Value
    'Calls the FindAll function
    Set FoundCells = FindAll(SearchRange:=SearchRange, _
                            FindWhat:=FindWhat, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            BeginsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            EndsWith:=vbNullString, _
                            BeginEndCompare:=vbTextCompare)
    If FoundCells Is Nothing Then
        ReDim arrResults(1 To 1, 1 To 5)
        arrResults(1, 1) = "Data not found!!!"

    Else
        'Add results of FindAll to an array
        ReDim arrResults(1 To FoundCells.Count, 1 To 5)
        lFound = 1
         For Each FoundCell In FoundCells
            If FoundCell.Column = 3 Then
                arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Value
                arrResults(lFound, 3) = FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 4) = FoundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                arrResults(lFound, 5) = FoundCell.Address
                lFound = lFound + 1
            Else
                If FoundCell.Column = 4 Then
                    arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
                    arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    arrResults(lFound, 3) = FoundCell.Value
                    arrResults(lFound, 4) = FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    arrResults(lFound, 5) = FoundCell.Address
                    lFound = lFound + 1
                Else
                    If FoundCell.Column = 5 Then
                        arrResults(lFound, 1) = FoundCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
                        arrResults(lFound, 2) = FoundCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
                        arrResults(lFound, 3) = FoundCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                        arrResults(lFound, 4) = FoundCell.Value
                        arrResults(lFound, 5) = FoundCell.Address
                        lFound = lFound + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            
        Next FoundCell
    End If
    
    'Populate the listbox with the array
    Me.ListBox_Results.List = arrResults
```

Code to display selected data in a user form:

```
Private Sub ListBox_Results_Click()
'Go to selection on the sheet when the result is clicked

Dim strAddress As String
Dim l As Integer

    For l = 0 To ListBox_Results.ListCount
        If ListBox_Results.Selected(l) = True Then
            strAddress = ListBox_Results.List(l, 4)
            Rownum = Range(strAddress).Row
            Colnum = Range(strAddress).Column
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Select
            Cells(Rownum, Colnum).Select
            'Populate textboxes with results
            'and maybe populate chart data range with results aswell????
            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results1.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 1).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results2.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 2).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results3.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 3).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results4.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 4).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results5.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 5).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results6.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 6).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results7.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 7).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results8.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 8).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results9.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 9).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results10.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 10).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results11.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 11).Value
                f_FindAll.TextBox_Results12.Value = .Cells(.Range(strAddress).Row, 12).Value
            End With
            GoTo EndLoop
        End If
    Next l

EndLoop:
    
End Sub
```

So what would be the best option? Maybe instead sort the data in sheet "Data" and create a chart from the selected range?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want to do these kind of things in F# with MS-SQL, I can tell you how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to build a collection of row numbers and then use them to create arrays for each series of the chart. Alternatively dump the array to another sheet and use that as the source data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PlotData()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim FindWhat As String, FirstFound As String
    Dim datarows As Collection, ar
    Dim r As Long, i As Integer, n As Integer
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data")
    Set datarows = New Collection
    Set rngSearch = ws.UsedRange.Columns("C:E")

    ' build collection of rows
    FindWhat = "11342"
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(FindWhat, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False)
    
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        ' no match
        Exit Sub
    Else
        FirstFound = rngFound.Address
        Do
            n = n + 1
            datarows.Add rngFound.Row, CStr(n)
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(After:=rngFound)
        Loop While Not rngFound Is Nothing And rngFound.Address <> FirstFound
    End If

    ' fill array
    ReDim ar(1 To n, 1 To 5), x(n - 1), y(n - 1)
    Dim sname
    sname = Array("date", "chol", "trig", "LDL", "HDL")
    For i = 1 To n
        With ws
           r = datarows(i)
           x(i - 1) = .Cells(r, "B") 'date
           ar(i, 1) = .Cells(r, "B") 'date
           ar(i, 2) = .Cells(r, "I") 'chol
           ar(i, 3) = .Cells(r, "J") 'trig
           ar(i, 4) = .Cells(r, "K") 'LDL
           ar(i, 5) = .Cells(r, "L") 'HDL
        End With
    Next

    ' copy to sheet if required as source data for plot
    'Sheet2.Range("A1:E1") = sname
    'Sheet2.Range("A2:E" & n + 1) = ar

    ' plot graph
    Dim cht As Chart, c As Integer, srs As Series
    Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlLineMarkers).Chart
    With cht
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = FindWhat
        For c = 2 To 5
            'Define the array of values for each series
            For i = 1 To n
                y(i - 1) = ar(i, c)
            Next
            Set srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With srs
                .XValues = x
                .Values = y
                .name = sname(c - 1)
            End With
        Next
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, name:=FindWhat
    End With

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah i figured the dumping solution just a few hours ago. Your code is much cleaner compared to mine :D Thank you for your help.